# Rewrite the recursion function with loop

Tags: python

To rewrite the function without using recursion.

```py
def func(num):
    if num < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return func(num - 1) + func(num - 2)
# TODO：to rewrite the func using 'loop' instead of 'recursion'.
```

Below may be a solution, but i do not think it is a good way as i am using the convience of 'list'.

```py
def func(num):
    """
    I use a list to simulate a queue, 
    it is initialized with the param 'num' passed in, 
    and then judge it, if it ge 2, pop it and append the two nums 'num - 1', 'num - 2'.
    And repeat it, if the number is lt 2, the index move to right by 1.
    When the index is equal to the 'length - 1' of the queue, the queue if fulled with '0' and '1',
    because 'func(0) = 1', 'func(1) = 1', the result is the length of the queue.
    """
    index = 0
    queue = [num]
    while True:
        value = queue[index]
        if value >= 2:
            queue.pop(index)
            queue.append(value - 1)
            queue.append(value - 2)
        else:
            if index == len(queue) - 1:
                break
            index += 1
    return len(queue)
```

Comment: Ask for better solutions.

Comment: [Examples of many ways to generate Fibonacci sequence](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Python)

Comment: Thanks very much, I see, it is a Fibonacci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task was interesting for me to solve, I cope with it the following way:

```
def f(num):
    if num < 2:  # margin condition
        return 1
    start_list = [num]  # create initial list
    while True:
        new_list = []  # list to store new elements
        changes = 0  # check if there was elements >=2 
        for element in start_list:
            if element >= 2:
                new_list.append(element - 1)
                new_list.append(element - 2)
                changes += 1
            else:
                new_list.append(element)
        start_list = new_list  # change start_list for new run
        print(start_list)
        if changes == 0:
            return len(start_list)
```

I made performance check num = 25

my solution speed:  0.14056860000000002

recursion speed: 0.03910620000000001

your not recursion solution: 1.6991333

So it is 10 times faster.

Thank you for the task!

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is really faster greatly than mime. Algorithm is magic, and i think it is a long way to go to write such code like yours. By the way, what does the function name `lol` mean?

Comment: @pythonist I am really sorry for function name, I am "a little bit" lazy person and often call temporary folders in my PC lol or LOL or KKK or XXX in my PC, I also often call temporary Python functions (which going to delete soon) this way. Sorry if I offended you, I 've just forgotten to change function name before copy paste to Stack Overflow :(  I changed it now, sorry again.